# Does GitLab accept Federation?

Tags: git, gitlab, federation, gitblit

I would like to make a federation sync between a GitBlit and a GitLab instance. Make federations with GitBlit is possible i know, but i don't find anything about federation in GitLab.

I tried to find :

- federations properties in `gitlab.rb` file
- federations fields in project or administrator settings
- hooks adaptater

Nothing found. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Federation is currently not supported, but there is a [related discussion in GitLab's Issue Tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4013).

Comment: You might also be interested in the activities around ForgeFed, a initiative around fedreating forges, i.e. not only GitLab but also platforms like Gogs and Gitea. https://framalistes.org/sympa/arc/git-federation/